# Redirecting & Requesting Login to Protect Directly Written Url

Tags: php, redirect

Currently I have been trying to create a very simple login page.But I want to go a bit far of it.

Im working on local.
Lets say we have an index.php and login.php page.
When I write localhost:8080/index.php on url bar, Im able to view this page.But I want it to require a login in order to redirect to index.php page.

Here is the login.php codes,I have no idea how am I supposed to redirect it when The url was entered,

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="login" action="">
<table align=center>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php



    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $username="admin";
        $password="admin";
        $uUsername=$_POST['username'];  // the username which User will enter
        $uPassword = $_POST['password'];// the password which User will enter

        if  ( $username != $uUsername || $password != $uPassword )
        {
            echo 'Incorrect username or password.Please try again';
        }

        else
        {
            header("refresh:0; url=deneme.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use the superglobal `$_SESSION`. Then in your protected pages, you do `if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) { /* do something */ } else { /* show content of page */ }` -- more reading at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: I know about sessions.But Im looking for another way to be able to do this.Thats why I said I kept it simple.Briefly,just looking for a different method

Comment: Sessions are widely used for this purpose, and it's very simple to use. I'm curious, why do you want to use another method? The alternative is to use cookies, but that's basically the same as using a session. Because you'll need something that recognizes the user after login, your options are narrowed down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, before anything outputs to the browser, you need to check if the user is authenticated or not, since `header()` must be called before any output. I would use sessions for this.

In the top of every file that requires an authenticated user (**except on the login-page**), I would add this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['authenticated'])) {
    // The user isn't authenticated, let's redirect the user to the login page
    header('location: login.php'); // Change 'login.php' to the correct page/url to the login page.
    exit; // Important to stop the script-execution after a header location.
}
```

This will redirect the user to the login page if the session isn't set (the user isn't authenticated).

On the login page, I would move the authenticate script to the top of the file (before `<html>`), and change it like this:

```
<?php
$errorMessage = null;

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username  = "admin";
    $password  = "admin";
    $uUsername = $_POST['username'];
    $uPassword = $_POST['password'];

    if  ( $username != $uUsername || $password != $uPassword ) {
        $errorMessage = 'Incorrect username or password. Please try again';
    } else {
        // Start the session and set authenticated as true.
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['authenticated'] = true;
        header('location: index.php'); // Again, change 'index.php' to the correct file/url
        exit;
    }
}
?>
<html>
....// the rest of the login form
```

Further down in the form, you can check if `$errorMessage` isn't `null` and show the error message where you want it.

The code for the authentication check should be moved to a separate file which you include in every file instead of hard code it in every file.